# Mail is not sent in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to mention first a very similar question I already found here, but the answer proposed there I did , but still its not working so am posting my problem here.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: GCI Contact Form
 * Plugin URI: http://www.example.com
 * Description: A Simple Plugin To Implement Contact Form into your WordPress Site
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Author: Parnasree Chowdhury
 * Author URI: http://www.example.com
 * License: GPL2
 */

 function html_form_code() {
 echo '<form method="post" action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '">';
                            echo '<fieldset>';
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-name" value="' .esc_attr( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? $_POST["cf-name"] : '' ) . '" placeholder="Name*" class="form-control form-dark" required/>';
                                    echo '<input type="email" name="cf-email" value="' . esc_attr( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ?  $_POST["cf-email"] : '' ) . '" placeholder="Email*" class="form-control form-dark" required/>';
                                    echo '<textarea rows="6" name="cf-message" placeholder="Message*" class="form-control form-dark" required>' . esc_attr( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? $_POST["cf-message"]  : '' ) . '</textarea>';
                                    echo '<input name="cf-submitted" class="btn btn-border border-white" type="submit" value="Submit" />';
                                    //echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="gci_deliver_mail" />';
                                    echo '<div class="loading"></div>';
                            echo '</fieldset>';
                            echo '</form>';
 }

 function gci_deliver_mail() {

    // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

        // sanitize form values
        $name    = sanitize_text_field($_POST["cf-name"]);
        $email   = sanitize_email($_POST["cf-email"]) ;
        $subject = "Enquiry message submitted from iceindia";
        $message = esc_textarea($_POST["cf-message"]);

        // get the blog administrator's email address
        $to = 'mymailid@gmail.com';

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';

        }
    }
}
function cf_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    gci_deliver_mail();
    html_form_code();

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'gci_contact_form', 'cf_shortcode' );
?>
```

The above is my contact-form plugin code.
I used the short code in my theme's front page like following : -->

```
  <div class="contact-form"> 
      <?php echo do_shortcode('[gci_contact_form]');?>
  </div>
```

It worked perfectly and the contact form is getting appeared in my theme's front page as it should be and even the form is getting submitted , but mail is not sent it's triggering the error i.e. echoing the error in the else part of the gci_deliver_mail() function.

Here is a screenshot where the error is occuring -->
http://tinyurl.com/omcp7zz
Thanks in advance

I added the following line in else part :->

```
var_dump($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Now the Output:
string(23) "mymaildid@gmail.com" string(39) "Enquiry message submitted from iceindia" string(4) "test" string(27) "From: par " An unexpected error occurred

Comment: Could you please `var_dump($to, $subject, $message, $headers)` in your else clause and edit the output of that into your question?

Comment: Worked perfectly fine in my local.

Comment: @Siguza I did as you told. Edited the question

Comment: Can you var_dump $email to? Because it seems that the email is not filled in to your header which will lead to an error.

Comment: tried, its filled and fetched the data as well

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";
```

to

```
$headers = "From: " . $name . " <" . $email. ">" . "\r\n";
```

maybe you have any unescaped data in $name

Answer (score 0):

As you have mention your output.I think your header had an error
Just remove or comment the header.Then it will sent mail to your mail.

//$headers = "From: $name " . "\r\n";
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your mail server is working properly or not.
You can install Easy SMTP mail plugin [Download From Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webriti-smtp-mail/).
Try to send the test mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use only the blog admin mail id which is registered while creating the blog in wordpress. 
example:
 *

> **if your blog name is example.com then use your mail id as admin@example.com*

**